# ValueError DataFrame constructor not properly called

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

```
billing_descrp= pd.DataFrame(customer.groupby('Invoice No')['Item No'])
print(billing_descrp)

raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Comment: You can't create a dataframe from a groupby object alone, what are you trying to do exactly? all you did was create a groupby object on `'Invoice No'` and then accessing a single column without calling any aggregating function

Comment: type `customer.groupby('Invoice No')['Item No']` and see what it returns

Answer (score 0):

It looks that **customer** is a DataFrame.

If it is, then you don't need to determinate it by *pd.DataFrame(..)*.

Let's try this:

```
billing_descrp= customer.groupby('Invoice No')['Item No'].count()
print(billing_descrp)
```

With count as an agregation function.

Comment: I've already used this code(billing_descrp= customer.groupby('Invoice No')['Item No'].count()), but this time, I want to get Items (identified by its number) along with Invoice number in order to understand the correlations between purchased items...

Comment: you can use first(). It will compute first of group values.